# How do I save user input per tab created through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project that allows a user to check off boxes per tab that is created through jQuery. The tabs are created when a user clicks on the Add button. Jquery generates a set of checkboxes per tab and should allow the user to check any number of boxes they want. The issue is that it looks like they share the same checkboxes since checking boxes in one tab transfers it over to the other tab. Is this something for Session Storage? Do I have to give each checkbox a unique name? Not quite sure if this is possible with just jQuery.

I realize that something like this would be easier using a stack but I am doing this to get a better understanding of that process.

Git: https://github.com/frfroylan/project_checklist 
Link: http://proj-checklist.surge.sh/

HTML:

```
<body onload="script()">

        <h1 class="h1-text">Product Checklist</h1>

        <div class="wrapper">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tabs">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active" id="newTab"><a href="#new" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab info -->
                <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="new">
                                <p>New Product name:</p>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="    Product Name" id="newProductName">
                                <button onclick="genLi()">Add</button>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
script = function(){
                newTabPanel = $('#new');
                newTab = $('#newTab');

                genLi = function(){
                                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                                var prodName = $('#newProductName').val();
                                var newLi = $('<li role="presentation" class="active" id="newTab"><a href="#' + prodName + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'+ prodName +'</a></li>');
                                newTab.before(newLi);
                                genNewTabCont(prodName);
                }
                genNewTabCont = function(id){
                                var newTabPane = $('HTML_TO_LONG_CHECK_GIT');
                                newTabPanel.before(newTabPane);
                }
}
```

Comment: Can't see the error on the link you provided. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: @andrescpacheco there is no error that gets outputted. The issue is that im trying to get each tab to hold their own separate checked check boxes.

Comment: Post all relevant code in question itself. Questions should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go off site and poke through a repo to try to review your issue. See [mcve]

Comment: seems to work for me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed the error does not occur, when you choose different names. DOM manipulation with jQuery is all about selectors. If you just use an data-attribute or class as selector your jQuery call will affect all matched elements. If you want every tab to be unique, you have to create unique ID selectors or reference them by their position.

```
$('.tab').eq(position);
```

Comment: I didnt realize that adding the same ID to the inputs per tab would resolve this issue. Thanks for the help!